# Storyboard will not save in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

So, for an independent programming class I am working in Xcode. I am using stanford's iOS development course to create a calculator. However, recently, the item *mainstoryboard.storyboard* has been unable to save. I removed the entitlement, which allowed the other files to save, but the storyboard has still been unable to save. I looked around on the internet a good deal, and all I've been able to dig up is that the file might be corrupted. What do I do for this? Is there anything I'm missing? I don't know what kind of context I should be providing, so please tell me if there's something you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, it was a problem with not having enough memory on the server. I've been looking at all the wrong things and can go back to working on my program. Thanks for all the help, too bad it was something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your derived Data and try to clean and clean the build folder (you do this with alt+clean).

If you can't save the file again try to create a new project create a storyboard. If you can't create it on this way then you have to get to the Apple Dev Forums there is a bigger Problem then.

But anyway if you create Storyboard the App only runs on iOS 5+ Devices. Not the best option imho.

Answer (score 1):

Clean all targets, close Xcode, reboot your mac. Then restart Xcode and create a new iPhoneStoryboard.storyboard and try again!
I've solved in this way this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the storyboard by clicking on it in the left pane and press delete button. When prompted choose delete rather than removing reference only. Then use command+n and in the popped window, choose storyboard and name it as MainStoryboard (Xcode will add .storyboard for you).